# Alter mysql database engine doesn't work from cluster to other

Tags: mysql, alter-table, ndbcluster, database-engine

I got into this issue when I tried to alter my database table engine to `InnoDB` from `ndbcluster`, It did not work. But When I changed engine from `InnoDB` to `ndbcluster` it worked.

It did not throw any error but did not work. I just want to know why this did not work as I got it from `MySQL` site that it won't work. I just need to know the reason for the same.

For client requirement I may need to alter the engine on installed database without losing any data.

Any Ideas or help that anybody can provide to resolve issue.

Answer (score 2):

**Why you can't change `ndbcluster` to `InnoDB`?**

Clustering with MySQL is supported only by the NDB storage engine. `ndbcluster/ndb` storage engine is meant for clustering if you specify a table with `ENGINE=ndbcluster;` this means table is being shared with all nodes and simply you can't change it to other `ENGINE` types, either you should take a backup of this table and then `DROP table` with `ndbcluster` option and import by changing `ndbcluster` to `innodb`

However, it is possible to create tables using other storage engines (such as InnoDB or MyISAM) on a MySQL server being used with a MySQL Cluster, but since these tables do not use `NDB`, they do not participate in clustering; each such table is strictly local to the individual MySQL server instance on which it is created.

**Migrating from InnoDB to ndbcluster?**

There are two ways to migrate InnoDB tables with foreign keys to NDB.

- Dump the database and edit the script so each table specifies ENGINE=NDB before re-importing the script to a new database
- Drop the constraints, alter the tables to use the NDB engine, and recreate the constraints

Dumping the database and editing the script is a straightforward use of mysqldump and a text editor.

[Converting InnoDB Tables to MySQL Cluster](https://blogs.oracle.com/jsmyth/entry/innodb_to_mysql_cluster)

Comment: I think it should have been incorporated into MySQL to change cluster to other. As if one need to migrate from NDB to other engine types. What would happen if I remove datanode mappings from .CNF files and try to change the engine to other?